# Find command to find Zip files with ignorecase

Tags: unix, find

Can some one tell me how to use Find command to find files of extension Zip,ZIP,zip. ?
find . -iname *.zip is not working for me in AIX.

Comment: Did you remember to quote the glob pattern? `find . -iname '*.zip'`

Comment: bash-3.00$ find . -iname '*.zip'
find: 0652-017 -iname is not a valid option.
bash-3.00$
This is what i get as output

Comment: Error output and version of `find` should be included in you question.

Comment: `find . -name '*.[Zz][Ii][Pp]'  `

Answer (score 3):

You need to uses quotes around the pattern matching part. So

```
find . -iname '*.zip'
```

will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your shell supports character classes as part of its wild-card processing, most do, try

```
find . -name '*.[Zz][Ii][Pp]'
```

`-iname` ? I don't know that one.

Yes, sorry, you need a starting directory, in this case the '.' that you have flagged as missing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: bash-3.00$ find -name '*.[Zz][Ii][Pp]'
Usage: find [-H | -L] Path-list [Expression-list]

This is not working :(

Comment: `find . -name '*.[Zz][Ii][Pp]' |head`

The above is working . Perhaps i missed '.' in find command. Thank you @Shelter